# How to completely remove a virtual machine from VirtualBox?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, virtualization

i have installed windows 7 on virtual Box 4.3.10

i have deleted the **VirtualBox.xml** configuration file in /home/larbi/.config/VirtualBox after that when i launch virtualBox i get no virtual machines in the menu .

so i need to know where i can find the virtual machine folder 
i'm using ubuntu 14.04

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default virtual machines are stored in your home folder, that is `/home/larbi/` in `VirtualBox VMs`.

Inside this folder you will find all your virtual machines.